# Need help building a Timeable skipping Weekends

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been tasked with writing a procedure which when given a course code and start date will schedule Modules on consecutive working days skipping weekends.

I have attempted for hours to solve this with no avail. I've just got no idea how to implement it so it skips Saturday and Sunday(without lots of code) and how to loop it so it schedules each module on a different day.

```
OPEN my_cur;

        my_loop: LOOP
            FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO my_code;

        IF complete THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO `session`
            (`code`, `date`)
            VALUES
            (my_code, pro_date);

        SET pro_date = DATE_ADD(pro_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

        END LOOP;

CLOSE my_cur;
```

END$$

CALL `schedule`('DDM', '2020.11.27');

I want the output to be a timetable which schdedules each module of a course on a different day ignoring weekends.

Comment: Please also specify with database server you are using (i.e. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server). Different DB has different possible implementations.

Comment: ahh my bad, MySQL specifically MYSQL workbench

Comment: Look for `WEEKDAY()` or `DAYOFWEEK()` function to identify weekends. Example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp